# django: how to add home link to admin

Tags: django, admin

I would like to add a link to `/` to every page in template. Can I do it without changing django internal template? I could customize django, but this is something I seriously wouldn't like to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just override one of the Django admin templates in your own `templates/admin` directory. For instance, copy the contents of `django/contrib/admin/templates/base.html` into `yourproject/templates/admin/base.html`. Then, change the latter to your heart's content.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

Comment: I have all templates in applications. Adding  `<myapp>/<templates>/<admin>/base_site.html` didn't help.

Comment: True, that won't work. It doesn't matter if all your other apps' templates are with the apps, you're still going to have to use `yourproject/templates/admin` for the admin stuff. All third-party template overrides work that way. If you were overriding auth templates, you'd have to add a `yourproject/templates/registration` directory.

Comment: I have created `templates/admin/base_site.html`, but there is no change. You have any idea, what else is required to be changed?

Comment: OK, I had add this path to settings file. Thanks, it works great.

Answer (score 1):

According to the accepted answer, I still failed to make it. After some try-error experiments, my answer is:

1. copy `django/contrib/admin/templates/base_site.html` to as `your_project/templates/admin/base_site.html`
2. customize your local `base_site.html` to whatever you want
3. add to your **settings.py**

   `TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('templates',)`