# Add non model based URL via AdminSite.get_urls not working

Tags: python, django

I tried to add an non model based URL to an admin page using get_urls member function:

```
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite
from django.conf.urls import url
from myapp.models import Bar

class StaffAdmin(AdminSite):
    site_header = 'My App'
    site_title = site_header
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(StaffAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            url(r'^foo/$', self.foo_view, name='foo'),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls
    def foo_view(self, request):
        context = dict(
            self.admin_site.each_context(request),
            key=value,
        )
        return TemplateResponse(request, 'foo_view.html', context)

staff_admin_site = StaffAdmin()
staff_admin_site.register(Bar)
```

Bar shows up OK on the staff admin page, but foo is missing.

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls

Comment: I was confusing AdminSite with admin.ModelAdmin, which is why it does not work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem of creating a custom link on the admin panel  by using the following steps:

Create a proxy model from the model:

```
from myapp.models import Foo

class FooProxy(Foo):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Register the proxy model:

```
admin.site.register(FooProxy)
```

Override the admin URL in urls.py (by putting the relevant pattern before the admin pattern):

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/myapp/fooproxy/$', FooView.as_view(), name='foo-view'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 6):

In Django >= 3.2 your custom admin urls should be at the top (before `catch_all_view`) of urls, otherwise you will get 404 from `django.contrib.admin.sites.catch_all_view`

```py
class StaffAdmin(AdminSite):
    def get_urls(self):
        my_urls = [
            url(r'^foo/$', lambda request: HttpResponse('Foo'), name='foo'),
        ]
        urls = super().get_urls()
        return my_urls + urls
```

Or you can set `AdminSite.final_catch_all_view` to `False` but is [not recommended](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.final_catch_all_view).

Answer (score 0):

The `foo_view` code you copied from the documentation is just an example, it will not work out of the box.

However, using a working view (using a simple lambda for this example) will work out fine:

```
class StaffAdmin(AdminSite):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(AdminSite, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            url(r'^foo/$', lambda request: HttpResponse('Foo'), name='foo'),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls
```

Visiting `/admin/foo/` in the browser displays the string 'Foo' *(if you're not using the admin prefix remove or change it with your own path)*

I assume you where expecting a link to magically appear in the admin index page. However convenient that might be, the index template will not know about your custom urls so you will have to override the template to add them.

[More about custom admin links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598484/django-how-to-add-home-link-to-admin)

Comment: I suspected I'd have to override the admin template as a look the source for the admin page shows it refers to "app.models", where "app" comes from a list of apps.   Do you mean to override the HTML or the actual AdminSite class?

Comment: overriding the template would be easier, you can write a context_processor or templatetag to get the required context or add content statically